# merge two array into one resultant array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

```
let array1 = [{name:"ABC",add:"XYZ"},{name:"PQR",add:"CCC"}];

let array2 = [1,2]
```

I want output to be

```
array1=[{name:"ABC",add:"XYZ",num:1},{name:"PQR",add:"CCC",num:2}];
```

And I was also wondering if my array2 was also array of object with a weird key name but in resultant array i want a good key name like

```
let array1 = [{name:"ABC",add:"XYZ"},{name:"PQR",add:"CCC"}];

let array2=[{weirdKey:1},{weirdKey:2}];
```

but resultant array will be neat like

```
array1=[{name:"ABC",add:"XYZ",num:1},{name:"PQR",add:"CCC",num:2}];
```

Comment: Will both arrays always be of equal size?

Comment: yes both will be same in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following will work for both your scenarios:

```
let array1 = [{ name: "ABC", add: "XYZ" }, { name: "PQR", add: "CCC" }];
let array2 = [{ weirdKey: 1 }, { weirdKey: 2 }];

array1.forEach((element, i) => {
  array1[i].num = array2[i].weirdKey ? array2[i].weirdKey : array2[i];
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: `array1[i]["num"]` will return the value of num, not the whole object

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you are trying to convey. But it gives the desired output for either of the conditions.

Comment: you use map to change globally, why?

Comment: OP wanted the change to be applied to `array1`

Comment: then uses forEach

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following (assuming the same length for both arrays):

```
array1 = array1.map((el, i) => {
    el.num = array2[i];
    return el;
});
```

**Edit**:
For your second case, you can do the following if you're not sure what the `weirdKey` will be:

```
array1 = array1.map((el, i) => {
    el.num = Object.values(array2[i])[0];
    return el;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

If array2 is just a list :

```
let array1 = [{name:"ABC",add:"XYZ"},{name:"PQR",add:"CCC"}];
                let array2 = [1,2];



                array1 = array1.map(function (item_1, index_1) {
                    array2.map(function (item_2, index_2) {
                        if (index_1 == index_2) {
                            item_1['num'] = item_2
                        }
                    });
                    return item_1
                });

                console.log(array1);
```

If array2 is list of objects , try this below :

```
array1 = array1.map(function (item_1, index_1) {
                    array2.map(function (item_2, index_2) {
                        if (index_1 == index_2) {
                            item_1['num'] = item_2['weirdKey']
                        }
                    });
                    return item_1
                });

                console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

simple pure function:

```
const combineToArrayFn =
  (array1, array2, key = '') =>
    array1.map((item, i) => ({...item, num: array2[i][key] || array2[i]}));

const newArray = combineToArrayFn(array1, array2);

const newArray1 = combineToArrayFn(array1, array2, 'weirdKey');
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more simpler:

```
array1.forEach((e,index)=>{
 array1[index]["num"]=array2[index].weirdKey;
});
```

maybe this can solve your problem.
you can also use simple for loop on array1 instead of forEach() or map() function.

Answer (score 1):

try use map() method for arrays

```js
// without weirdKey
let array1 = [{ name: "ABC", add: "XYZ" }, { name: "PQR", add: "CCC" }]
let array2 = [1, 2];

array1.map((item, index) => item.num = (array2[index].weirdKey) ? array2[index].weirdKey : array2[index])
console.log(array1)

// with weirdKey same function
let array3 = [{ name: "ABC", add: "XYZ" }, { name: "PQR", add: "CCC" }]
let array4 = [{ weirdKey: 1 }, { weirdKey: 2 }];

array3.map((item, index) => item.num = (array4[index].weirdKey) ? array4[index].weirdKey : array4[index])
console.log(array3)
```

Comment: can u tell me when to use map and when to use forEach?

Comment: forEach use when you don’t need to return any result